# Return single number of divs not just their total

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have this function that gives me that TOTAL number of divs, how can I change it to have a result like this: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07?

Thanks in advance

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  $(document.body).append($(".slide"));
  var n = $(".slide").length;
  $("span").text("0" + n);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span></span>

<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
<div class=slide></div>
```

Comment: The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question (including your HTML, for instance), ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`$('div').each(function(i) {
    $("span").append("0" + (i + 1) + '<br />');
});`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/aj5x8ptw/1/)

Comment: update https://jsfiddle.net/tsobott7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/tsobott7/5/

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {
  $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
  var n = $( "div" ).length;
  var str = "";
  for (var x = 1; x < n; x++) {
    str = str + "\n0" + x;
  }
  $( "span" ).text(str);
})
```

You can do it by just using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsobott7/4/)

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
    var n = $( "div" ).length;
    
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    $("span" ).append( "0" + i+'\u00A0');
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I see extra `,` at the end.

Comment: This is *really* inefficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for why?Its satisfied his requirement

Comment: I never said it didn't. I said it was inefficient. It does repeated DOM lookups and repeated DOM manipulations to fill in the `span` where a single lookup and manipulation would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload=function(){
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var span=document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var divsLength=divs.length;
  var count=1;
  
  for(var index=0;index<divsLength;index++)
    {
      var label=document.createElement('label');
      label.innerText='0'+count;
      span[0].append(label);span[0].append(" " );
      count++;
    }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```js
$(document.body).ready(function() {
    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>7th</div>" ) );
    $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
      ( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    });
    
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<div>1st</div>
<div>2nd</div>
<div>3rd</div>
<div>4th</div>
<div>5th</div>
<div>6th</div>
```